# Where can I find the maximize icon file?

Tags: themes, icons

I need the maximize icon file of the default elementary theme. I'm working on a custom theme for Vivaldi, so that it looks more integrated, and this is the only one I can't find.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened an issue on GitHub and Cassidy replied pointing me to the actions/symbolic folder of their icons repo: https://github.com/elementary/icons/blob/master/actions/symbolic/window-maximize-symbolic.svg.

The parent directory has the rest of window controls and other symbolic icons for actions.

Comment: Please mark your answer as **answer**.

Answer (score 2):

I know what you are looking for is another type of icons but I really don't know where to look. I tried to find them but nothing.

There's a GitHub page where the normal icons are developed (not the kind you want/need). You could ask [there](https://github.com/elementary/icons/) and get a better answer than mine

https://github.com/elementary/icons/

Sorry and good luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Yes, I found that repo too, but I wanted to check here first before opening an issue. The icon doesn't seem to be present in the gtk theme folder either. Are you sure I can open an issue on GitHub if it's just a support question? It's not really a bug nor an icon contribution...

Comment: I'm not sure but at least you can get a direct input from a developer/maintainer. Yes probably will be off topic but you could get the next step as an answer

Comment: It got labeled as invalid, but Cassidy kindly answered my question. See my answer to this question :)